# British "pot" of whipping cream?

Tags: cream

In Great Britain, recipes often call for a "pot" of something.
Is a "pot" of whipping cream whipped or un-whipped?

Comment: "Pot"? Can you quote a recipe that uses this? On the face of it, if it says "[measurement] of whipping cream", I'd expect it to be unwhipped, while "[measurement] of whipped cream" could be expected to be whipped, but recipe writers are often sloppy with their language. What do other, similar recipes say?

Comment: if it's 'whipping cream' it's unwhipped.  The 'pot' is likely the size container it usually comes in ... but I have no idea what size that might be.

Comment: I've seen British recipes that call for "a pot" of stock as well. Apparently it's a common measurement.

Answer (score 3):

A pot of whipping cream is 270-290ml whipping cream.

Whipping cream is somewhere between single and double cream.

I'd love to get scientific with you but it's Christmas eve and the alcohol is flowing.